# Discrete Math Letters (Combination or Permutation)?

Tags: analysis, discrete-mathematics

### Question:

Given the letters $a, b, c.$ How many ways to arrange these letters?

Assuming 3 letters.

### Logical Question:

How do you know if you need to use permutations or combinations for this question ?

$P(3,3)$ or $C(3,3)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use permutations, so the answer is $3!=6$. 
Using combination does not make much sense since it would be equivalent to count the number of ways you can take $3$ letters out of a set of $3$ letters, which is only $1$. Indeed $C(3,3)=\frac{3!}{1!\cdot 3!}=1$.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean, I only use combinations if I am ask to do so, else I need to use permutations.

Comment: You use combination whenever the order does not count. If the order wasn't important in your question, then $abc$ and $bca$ (for instance) would be considered the same.

Comment: I see so abc and bca would have been considered 1 arrangement which is $3\choose3$ = 1

Comment: Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: Yes, if the order didn't count all the $6$ combinations $abc,acb,bac,bca,cab,cba$ would be considered exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

The order of the letters is important here. Hence you need to use permutations.

Comment: Why is it important ? You can start with either of a, b, c.

Comment: Well, you just answered your own question!! How do you count the number of arrangements of the letters $a,b,c$? First you need to choose the first letter: $3$ choices. Then you choose the second letter from the remaining $2$: $2$ choices. Then you have $1$ choice for the last letter, the letter that wasn't chosen already. By the rule of product, the number you seek is $3\cdot2\cdot1=3!$ which is the number of permutations of the three letters.

Comment: The number of $3$-combinations of the $3$ letters will give you $1$. In a sense, it gives you the number of arrangements in alphabetical order only and so it counts only the arrangement $abc$.

Comment: So you mean if I am asked to find the # of arrangements of a,b,c I use permutations or 3! unless the question explicitly asks to find the # of combinations of a,b,c ?

Comment: Basically, yeah.

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thank you for your help.

Comment: so simply there are variations without repetitions